# Integrating retail version of Bad Company 2 with Steam

Tags: steam, battlefield-bad-company-2

I've found out that I can't just use a retail CD-Key for Bad Company 2 in Steam.

However, is there a way to integrate with Steam, so I can for example easily play BC2 with Steam friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go your steam library and select "Add a game"->"Add a non-steam game" then find the executable for BF:BC2, this will show your friends when you are playing BC2.  You will also be able to access the in-game overlay for PMing your steam friends and using the browser.  Sadly, it won't show any details about the server you are on, just that you are playing it.

This is the best you can currently integrate non-steam games into steam (games that don't have a steam-activatable key, at least).

Comment: Actually I've tried that. It only shows it in Steam as BFBC2.exe, and as you've already said, no way of inviting friends to join a game :-/

Comment: This is actually exactly how the Steam version works, apart from the self-updating part. As far as I know, you can't really invite players to your BC2 game via the Steam client.

Comment: that sux... :-(

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly BC2 has an in-game friends list. Have all your friends add each other to their in-game friends list and then you can join the same games right from inside the game, Steam or no Steam.